# Null Value in Label object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created on GridView with Label. I have written store procedure to get StatusCode

```
SELECT StatusCode
From TableName
```

This line in GridView

< asp:Label ID="lblStatusCode" runat="server" Visible="false"

Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StatusCode")%>' />

These lines in .cs file

```
Label lblStatusCode = (Label)row.FindControl("lblStatusCode");
objJV.Status = Convert.ToInt32(lblStatusCode.Text);
```

but in `lblStatusCode.Text` it is showing *NULL* even though there is value in Table.

When I execute stored procedure independently it is giving values.

// bind function

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindJVJobValidationDetails();

        }


    }
```

protected void BindJVJobValidationDetails()
        {

```
        JVSummary objJV = new JVSummary();

        DataSet dataJobValidation = new DataSet();

        if (SessionVariables.PERID != null)
        {

            dataJobValidation = objJV.GetjvTransaction(SessionVariables.PERID);

            gvEmployee.DataSource = dataJobValidation;
            gvEmployee.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

What might be the problem...?

Comment: You need to explain where those lines of code in your CS reside

Comment: I have written on submit function to store that value into a table after click event of a  button in the GridView

Comment: StatusCode column values are not null. But in lblStatusCode.Text has null.

Comment: See my answer it explains your problem.

Comment: Are you checking it in the datarow? or header row?

Comment: Yeah I'm checking. If it is DataControlRowType.DataRow then only I'm trying to get that lblStatusCode.Text

Comment: I executed this same code in my friend PC it is working. and the value in lblStatusCode.Text is showing properly. But in my system it is showing NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

The text is applied to the control on the page AFTER the code behind runs. Can't you set the text in the code behind?

Edit: You are setting the value of the label on the page i.e aspx / ascx using `Container.DataItem` but this value is set after the code behind has run. Basically, when the code behind looks at the control it's text property hasn't been set yet. Instead, add a DataRowBinding event to your GridView and set the lblStatusCode.Text in the event in the code behind.

Comment: I did not get you. Could you explain me please.

Comment: I bound values to GridView. Could you see my edit n question. I that I have pasted my binding functions

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code on `gridview`'s event 
`OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound"`

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.DataItem) != null)
        {
            Label lblStatusCode = (Label)e.row.FindControl("lblStatusCode");
            objJV.Status = Convert.ToInt32(lblStatusCode.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Data is binding properly. But when try to get data from the grid view the value in lblStatusCode.Text has null.

Comment: I executed this same code in my friend PC it is working. and the value in lblStatusCode.Text is showing properly. But in my system it is showing NULL value.